# Best seats in a bus if travelling with kids

Tags: europe, buses, children

Which are the best seats in a bus if travelling with kids (aged 1 and 3)? We will be travelling in Europe, partly between France and Belgium, partly Belgium to Amsterdam.

Answer (score 3):

see this [Are there any rules of thumb for the most comfortable seats on a long distance bus?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85559/are-there-any-rules-of-thumb-for-the-most-comfortable-seats-on-a-bus)

And move a few rows towards the bathroom if wanting easier access to the bathroom when needing to change diapers (if applicable).